# JavaScript: calculate the average of an odd number

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, average

I want to count the average value of the odd numbers from a list of numbers. I have a starting code to count the average, but I don't know how can I choose only the odd numbers from the list?

Here is my code:

```
var numberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6], thisTotal=0,thisAverage=0;

for (var i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++) {
    thisTotal += numberArray[i];
}

thisAverage = (thisTotal/numberArray.length);

alert(thisAverage)
```

Comment: please share your code completely

Comment: how about just change to `i+=2` instead of `i++`

Comment: Just like @tipsfedora said, but then divide by number of odd numbers not the `numberArray.length`

Comment: @tipsfedora Your comment will do odd indexes, not odd values. Assume the list changes to all even numbers but 1 odd and your solution fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to return only the odd numbers:

```
var oddArray = numberArray.filter(function(val) {
  return val % 2 !== 0;
});
```

Full example:

```js
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var thisTotal = 0;
var thisAverage = 0;

var oddArray = numberArray.filter(function(val) {
  return val % 2 !== 0;
});
console.log(oddArray); // [1, 3, 5]

var thisTotal = oddArray.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) { return  accumulator + currentValue;
});
console.log(thisTotal); // 1 + 3 + 5 => 9

var thisAverage = thisTotal / oddArray.length;
console.log(thisAverage); // 9 / 3 => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numberArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6], thisAverage=0,oddlength=0;

for(var i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++)
{
if(numberArray[i]%2!==0){
thisAverage+=numberArray[i];
oddlength++;
}
}

thisAverage=(thisAverage/oddlength);

alert(thisAverage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can get what you want by this.

```
var numberArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6], thisTotal=0,thisAverage=0;

for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  thisTotal += numberArray[i * 2];

  thisAverage= (thisTotal/numberArray.length);
}

console.log(thisAverage);
```

or if you want **general solution**, use this.

```
var numberArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...on and on], thisTotal=0,thisAverage=0;

for(var i=0; i < Math.ceil(numberArray.length() / 2); i++) {
  thisTotal += numberArray[i * 2];

  thisAverage= (thisTotal/numberArray.length);
}

console.log(thisAverage);
```

hope my code be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` to add and count.

```js
var numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = numberArray.reduce((a, n) => {
      if (n % 2 !== 0) {
        a.sum += n;
        a.count++;
      }
      
      return a;
    }, {sum: 0, count: 0}),
    average = result.sum / result.count;

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are in an array, you can do this:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var info = numbers.filter(function(n) { return n % 2 !== 0})
                 .reduce(function(acc, item) {
                     return {sum: acc.sum + item, count: acc.count + 1}
                 }, {sum: 0, count: 0});
var avg = info.sum / info.count;
```

This example uses `filter` and `reduce` methods, which are declarative and more clear.
`filter` returns a new array with the items for which the function returns `true`, and then `reduce`, for each item, updates an 'accumulator'. The accumulator can be anything, and in this case is an object with the sum of the numbers and their count. For each item, we add add the current number to the `sum` property and add 1 to `count`. Finally, we just devide `sum` by `count` and done.

Answer (score -1):

```
var acc = 0, oddCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    if(numberArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      acc += numberArray[i];
      oddCount++;
    }
}

return acc / oddCount;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new array and store odd values in that array and after that you can apply your logic to that array.

```js
var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11];
var ar=[];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] % 2 !== 0) {
        ar.push(a[i]);      
    }  
}
 console.log(ar);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var numberArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
        var count = 0;
        var result = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i <= (numberArray.length-1); i++)
        {
            if (numberArray[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                result += numberArray[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        alert(result / count);
```